# linear regression prediction values are in negative and big decimal

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, dataset, linear-regression

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(Xtrain, ytrain)
pred=lr.predict(Xtest)
pred
```

My Ytest value is something like this

```
Price_euros
248 675.0
556 255.0
693 2590.0
387 1369.0
781 2350.0
... ...
468 1699.0
508 1323.0
1187    691.0
1010    949.0
1053    979.0
```

But
predicted value is something like:

```
0   7.547000e+02
1   -7.503793e+10
2   2.169000e+03
3   -4.296977e+09
4   1.020596e+10
... ...
256 -7.759706e+09
257 -5.626814e+09
258 7.135000e+02
259 8.365000e+02
260 8.423000e+02
```

Is it a decimal problem? How to round off the predicted value and predicted value should not be in negative isn't it??

MSE is 6.255155054767432e+20

I dont think this is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linear regression is an **affine model**, in the sense that the prediction is of form

```
f(x) = <w, x> + b = SUM_i w_i x_i + b
```

What this means in practise is that **there are always some inputs, for which it will output negative values**. It has nothing to do with what you train on, it is a property of linear models.

```
1   -7.503793e+10
2   2.169000e+03
3   -4.296977e+09
4   1.020596e+10
... ...
256 -7.759706e+09
257 -5.626814e+09
258 7.135000e+02
259 8.365000e+02
260 8.423000e+02
```

All `e+02` and `e+03` are results very much in your data range, since these are hundreads and thousands. Now why are there some really off the charts? Again, **because it is a linear model**, which literally is multiplying each of your inputs by some weight, and adds them up. It is a very rigid, limited class of models, and thus to minimise the error, sometimes it needs to make huge mistakes.